# "a not unusual" or "not an unusual"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

The following example is from the book *Oxford Guide to English Grammar* describing *Not* usage

> **Beggars are *a not unusual* sight on the streets of London.**

Should that be

> **Beggars are *not an unusual* sight on the streets of London.**

**"a not unusual"** in the first sentence seems not idiomatic or right to me.

Can anybody explain this to me? How a native speaker would say this?

Also I want to know the two negative words "not unusual" is all right to use?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not a native speaker, but that double negative sounds more emphatic than a normal positive sentence. A not unusual sight sounds natural to me.

Comment: It sounds pretentious to me, but that is just my taste.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing grammatically wrong with "a not unusual sight." Some find it a stylistically verbose and pretentious way to say "a usual sight."

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can I use "not an unusual" there, because that is more convenient than the other to me.

Comment: Yes, you can use it: it is grammatical. Some consider it poor style.  And clearly "not an unusual" is more round-about and harder to comprehend quickly than " a usual," but that is style, not grammar.